# C++ find special char and move to the end of a string

Tags: c++, string, boolean-expression, boolean-operations

I am currently a student taking C++. My issue is that my nested if statement does not find the special chars if they are at the end of the word. From what I can tell, it does not run the function at all. If anyone has any idea what is wrong that will be great!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

bool isVowel(char ch);
string rotate(string pStr);
string pigLatinString(string pStr);
bool specialChar(char ch);

int main() {
    string str, str2, pigsentence, finalsentence, orgstr, end;
    int counter, length, lengtho;
    counter = 1;
    cout << "Enter a string: ";
    getline (cin, str);
    cout << endl;

    orgstr = str;

    //Add in option to move special chars
    string::size_type space;
        do {
            space = str.find(' ', 0); //Finds the space(s)
            if(space != string::npos){
                str2 = str.substr(0, space); //Finds the word
                    if(specialChar(str[true])) { //Finds special char
                        end = str.substr(space - 1); //Stores special char as end
                        cout << end << endl; //Testing end
                        str.erase(space - 1); //Erases special car
                    }
                str.erase(0, space + 1); //Erases the word plus the space
                pigsentence = pigLatinString(str2); //converst the word
                finalsentence = finalsentence + " " + pigsentence + end; //Adds converted word to final string
            }else {
                length = str.length();
                str2 = str.substr(0, length); //Finds the word
                    if(specialChar(str[true])) { //Finds special char
                        end = str.substr(space - 1); //Stores special char as end
                        cout << end << endl; //Testing end
                        str.erase(space - 1); //Erases special car
                    }
                str.erase(0, length); //Erases the word
                pigsentence = pigLatinString(str2); //converst the word
                finalsentence = finalsentence + " " + pigsentence + end; //Adds converted word to final string
                counter = 0;
            }
        }while(counter != 0); //Loops until counter == 0

    cout << "The pig Laten form of " << orgstr << " is: " << finalsentence << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The function that lists the specialChars is below

```
bool specialChar(char ch) {
    switch(ch) {
    case ',':
    case ':':
    case ';':
    case '.':
    case '?':
    case '!':
        return true;
    default:
        return false;
    }
}
```

I do have other functions but they are working and just convert a word to piglatin.

Comment: beside your question, are you trying to create a [parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing)?

Comment: could you explain what you mean with `if(specialChar(str[true]))` in particular the argument `str[true]` ?

Comment: @itwasntpete We have not learned anything about parsing so I am going to say no.

Comment: @claptrap what I was wanting that to do is run the function specialChar on the variable str and see if it is true. I tried other formats but I believe I am not creating an array on True.

Comment: @aDroidman it is never to late ;)

Comment: @aDroidman no that makes no sense, str is a string so if you write str[true] then true is interpreted as an integer typically 1 so what you are doing is to check if the second character in the string is a "special character"

Comment: @claptrap I am trying to check each word to see if it has a special char. I understand my code is incorrect and needs improvement, but I do not know how to fix it. Which is what I am trying to find out.

Comment: @aDroidman then you need to loop through the word to check for the character e.g. `for ( int i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i ) { if ( ispecialChar(str[i]) ) { ... } }`

Comment: @aDroidman you also have some other issues in your code e.g. when you do not find space you still write `end = str.substr(space - 1)`

Answer (score 0):

You're using `true` as your array index when passing arguments to the `specialChar()` function! Surely that isn't what you meant to do. Fix that and you might see some improvement.

Think of the function call broken down a little, like this, to help you keep track of the types:

```
// takes a char, returns a bool, so....
bool specialChar( char in )
{ ... }

for( int i = 0; i < str.size(); i++ )
{
    char aChar = str[i];

    // ...pass in a char, and receive a bool!
    bool isSpecial = specialChar(aChar);
    if( isSpecial )
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

There's generally no harm in writing the code in a way that makes it clearer to you what's going on, when compiled and optimised it will all likely be the same.

Comment: That makes sense.... how can I return true/false when going from a string to char?

Comment: You use the position of the character you wish to examine as the string index.  The `specialChar()` function accepts that character as an argument, and will return a bool (true or false) because its *return* type is bool - not because of the arguments.

Answer (score 0):

your isSpecialChar takes a character as argument so str[index] would be something you could pass but instead you write str[true] which is not correct. If you want to check if there is a specialChar in your string you need to loop through the whole string and check each character.

It seems as if you want to split up a string into words so you could write something like this

```
char Seperator = ' ';

std::istringstream StrStream(str);
std::string Token;
std::vector<std::string> tokens;

while(std::getline(StrStream, Token, Seperator))
{
  tokens.push_back(Token);
}
```

now that you have the words in a vector you can do whatever what you want
with them like checking for a special char

```
for (int i = 0; i < tokens.size(); ++i)
{
  std::string& s = tokens[i];
  for (int j = 0; j < s.length(); ++j)
  {
    if ( specialChar( s[j] )
    {
      ...do whatever...
    }
  }
}
```